# Error more dependent variables than equations

Tags: warning-messages

This may be a stupid question but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, my mathematica code rejects the equation as having too many dependent variables, Error: There are more dependent variables than equations so the system is undefined:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Clear[derivative]

parameters = {k -> 100000, Slope -> 0.1, OptimumNumberA -> 40000, 
   OptimumNumberB -> 40000, OptimumNumberC -> 40000};

FitA = FA[t] == ((OptimumNumberA - NA[t])*Slope) + 1;
FitB = FB[t] == ((OptimumNumberB - NB[t])*Slope) + 1;
FitC = FC[t] == ((OptimumNumberC - NC[t])*Slope) + 1;
FitAB = FAB[t] == (FA[t] + FB[t]);

Frequency =
 NDSolve[{NA'[t] == (FitA*NA[t])/k, NB'[t] == (FitB*NB[t])/k, 
    NC'[t] ==(FitC*NC[t])/k, NAB'[t] == (FitAB*NAB[t])/k, 
    NA[0] == 34000, NB[0] == 30000, NC[0] == 20000, NAB[0] == 10000, 
    FA[0] == 0.3; FB[0] == 0.4, FC[0] == 0.5} /. parameters, {NA, NB, 
   NC, NAB}, {t, 0, 10000}]
```

Comment: You are using double equals in your "fit" equations.  Perhaps you mean single equals?

Comment: Thanks LouisB and Alex, this seems to have worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove unnecessary definitions

```
parameters = {k -> 100000, Slope -> 0.1, OptimumNumberA -> 40000, 
   OptimumNumberB -> 40000, OptimumNumberC -> 40000};

FitA = ((OptimumNumberA - NA[t])*Slope) + 1;
FitB = ((OptimumNumberB - NB[t])*Slope) + 1;
FitC = ((OptimumNumberC - NC[t])*Slope) + 1;
FitAB = FitA + FitB;

Frequency = 
 NDSolve[{NA'[t] == (FitA*NA[t])/k, NB'[t] == (FitB*NB[t])/k, 
    NC'[t] == (FitC*NC[t])/k, NAB'[t] == (FitAB*NAB[t])/k, 
    NA[0] == 34000, NB[0] == 30000, NC[0] == 20000, NAB[0] == 10000, 
    FA[0] == 0.3; FB[0] == 0.4, FC[0] == 0.5} /. parameters, {NA, NB, 
   NC, NAB}, {t, 0, 10000}]
{Plot[NA[t] /. Frequency, {t, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[NB[t] /. Frequency, {t, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[NC[t] /. Frequency, {t, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[NAB[t] /. Frequency, {t, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure1]